# Can not make method with same parameter types

Tags: c#

I am having 2 Entity to Dto map methods with the same parameter which is not allowed for the same name.

Is the only problem to solve give ToDto a better name? Actually I like ToDto

and having some methods with ToDto or another ToEditSchoolyearDto seems inconsistent here.

Is there any other solution?

```
public static BrowseSchoolyearDTO ToDto(this Schoolyear schoolyear)
{
   return new BrowseSchoolyearDTO
   {
      // mapping props
   };
}

public static EditSchoolyearDTO ToDto(this Schoolyear schoolyear)
{
   return new EditSchoolyearDTO
   {
      // mapping props
   };
}
```

Comment: What are the methods doing? Are the `Dto`s related? Could a tool like AutoMapper help here?

Comment: I just removed automapper because there will be much more difficult entity to DTO mappings where I can not speak anymore of an auto mapping...

Comment: @Elisa: Don't know your specific situation but you can always employ custom type resolvers when simple auto mapping does not work for you.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I have read some days about those a bit but still I would have to set it up. I can do it the same with Linq in my extensions method. Its a small project I dont care ;-) But if you have a good link how to map multiple DTOs into another DTOs property with custom logic go on and throw a link at me I am grateful ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you expect the compiler to work out which one you meant? Yes, if you're trying to create different methods with the same parameters, you need to give them different names.

I would suggest `ToBrowseDto` and `ToEditDto`. Then it's clear which you mean.

Comment: As I understand return type covariance it is not supported in C#.

Comment: @Sid: That's not the problem here - for example, Java *does* support return type covariance, but it doesn't mean you can overload a method using the same parameters but different return types.

Comment: your right on the answer and it definitely solves the purpose. but what is was trying to say it that what the Question Sample snippet had was a return type covariance. Correct me if thats a wrong understanding

Comment: @Sid: It *is* an incorrect understanding. Return type covariance is to do with overriding one method by providing a method with a "narrower" return type, or doing the same with interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can't distinguish methods with the same parameters based on return type.  For example if I wrote this code:

```
var dto = someSchoolyear.ToDto();
```

or this code:

```
object dto = someSchoolyear.ToDto();
```

what is the type of dto?

Comment: Also `someSchoolyear.ToDto();` as a statement by itself, where the return value is not picked up, is an example.